# Is it an optimized algorithm to add elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
def sum_of_array(arr1):                                       #sum in a list using o(logn) complexity 
    
    
    
    s,i=0,0
   
    
  
   
    while(i<len(arr1)//2):
            
        s=arr1[i]+arr1[len(arr1)-i-1]+s
        i=i+1
        
    return s

def odd_even(arr1):
    
    first=0
    last=len(arr1)-1
    mid=(first+last)//2
    
    if(len(arr1)%2==0):
        result1=sum_of_array(arr1)
        return result1
    elif(len(arr1)%2!=0):
        result2=sum_of_array(arr1)+arr1[mid]
        return result2
    
    

list_of_nos=[0,2,3,4,5,6,7]
result=odd_even(list_of_nos)
print(result)
```

Trying to know how any problem gets broken down and finding an optimized algorithm and weather this is an efficient way to add elements in a list

Comment: This isn't any more efficient than just looping through all the elements in the list and adding them together.


Both are O(n) time complexity


The overhead of checking whether the list length is odd or even would probably make this slightly less efficient in fact (though doesn't change the time complexity)

Comment: Will you recommend an algorith to add elements in a list in a more efficient way using an efficient algorithm